# Unable to uninstall a WiX Patch

Tags: wix, patch, uninstallation

I am working on a Patch sample using the following link. However, I am not able to uninstall the patch either from Control Panel or from the command line MSIEXEC /i "MsiPath" MSIPATCHREMOVE="PathToMSP"

[Peter Marcu's Blog: WiX: Building a Patch using the new Patch Building System - Part 3](http://petermarcu.blogspot.in/2007/06/wix-building-patch-using-new-patch_29.html)

Can anyone please let me know how to successfully uninstall or rollback a patch?
Note: I have set the AllowRemoval attribute to "yes" in the Patch.wxs file for the Patch element.

Comment: Does a verbose log say anything about the removal attempt? Or does the build output for the patch mention anything relevant?

Comment: Sorry. Actually, it was showing the error message "error opening installation log file. verify that the specified location exists and is writable wix"

Answer (score 0):

I would turn off logging, because apparently it's unable to perform the logging. Or try an explicit log location on your uninstall command line. Also, it could be this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2564571/-error-opening-installation-log-file--verify-that-the-specified-locate

and a detour is suggested.